# Identification of the bug on the curry leaf- Delhi, India

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

I found this bug on my curry leaf in early morning. Which bug is this?
Size- 1-2 cm
Habitat- Delhi, India.
The bug was on one of the curry leaf of the curry plant pot in my residential balcony
Time- 7:00 am

Comment: Identifications questions should also include an estimate of the size of the organism and as much habitat information as possible. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also consider taking the [tour] and going through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyresome I have edited. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You're welcome! That looks like what is commonly known as a shield or stink bug (a large and very diverse group of beetles) . If you don't get a more specific answer you might try submitting your observation to a site like [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=6681&taxon_id=47743), which specializes in species identifications.